# Confirm before: close the current page, change the url, leave the current 'page'

Tags: knockout.js, sammy.js

I am working on the page which has several levels using knockoutjs and sammyjs.

e.g. HOME / LEVEL1 / LEVEL2 / CURRENT

I have already finished the confirmation function:

How can I make it like: when people want to leave the CURRENT page, the confirmation message will appear to make sure they actually want to leave this page (go to HOME, LEVEL1, LEVEL2, .. or actually close the tab, change the url) or not.

Answer (score 0):

Within `var app = $.sammy(function() {...});` add the following:

```
// Will run at #/route but not at #/
this.before('#/route', function() {
    if(!window.confirm('Are you sure you want to leave this page?')) {
        return false;
    }
});

// will run at #/ but not at #/route
this.before({except: {path: '#/route'}}, function() {
    if(!window.confirm('Are you sure you want to leave the home page?')) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Source: [Sammy.Application before ( options, callback )](http://sammyjs.org/docs/api/0.6.3/Sammy.Application._methods_.before)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know this function and it seems like it almost done, but 1. once you click on Cancel, the page will still be there but url is changed.   2. I want to have a confirm message showing only leaving that specific page.

Comment: The URL won't change if you use a click binding (jQuery, Knockout.js, etc.) rather than an anchor tag. Then within the click binding, you change the URL if the confirm evaluates to true. So take the code above and put it inside your binding rather than within Sammy.